# Trying to use Selenium and Python and get the link from a button

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to use Selenium and Python to get all the links from specific buttons that are on the page.

But the button has no `a href` attribute to return.

Here's the code I've tried. Is there any way I can get these links even though the button doesn't have the attribute?

```
# Web page url request
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/ads/library/?active_status=all&ad_type=all&country=BR&q=myshopify&sort_data[direction]=desc&sort_data[mode]=relevancy_monthly_grouped&search_type=keyword_unordered&media_type=all')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(10)

ad_info = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/span/div/div')
links = []
for i in ad_info:
            links.append(i.get_attribute('href'))
```

I'm posting a snapshot of the buttons I'm trying to get the links from.

[image: Snapshot highlighting the buttons]

Comment: Which button is that? Can you show us through a snapshot? Is it just a button or groups of button ?

Comment: I am not able to locate this xpath `//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/span/div/div`

Comment: I've posted a snapshot.

Comment: `See ad details` don't really have an URL. Even if you click manually you would not see any change in the URL.

Comment: In that case I'll use Selenium to click all the buttons one by one and get the info I want inside the page. I've tried that and it worked. I just thought that with the links it would be faster, as Selenium wouldn't need to click the buttons and actully go inside the page.